# Gzip compression not applying to javascript files

Tags: .htaccess, gzip

I have several javascript files that are not being compressed, as far as I can tell via scans like Pagespeed insights and GtMetrix. I have the following code in my .htaccess file to enable compression.

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

I have also tried adding the following line but got no difference

mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/javascript.*

What needs to be done?

Thanks

Comment: I need a little bit more information. Are these JavaScript files external?

Comment: No they are not